# Binding to a Binding: Data Binding indirection -or- Metabinding in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

No way to explain this issue except by example:

Say you have a custom `UserControl` with two `DependencyProperty`s, `StatList Stats` and `string ImportantStat`. The job of the user control is to display a table showing all of the values in `Stats` but with special visual treatment (like a pie chart) of the `ImportantStat`.

My instinct was to write a block of XAML that looked more or less like:

```
<PieChart Value="{Binding Path={Binding ImportantStat} }"/>
```

where the `DataContext` is prior set to `Stats`. So, the user passes in `ImportantStat = "WinPercentage"` and the pie chart binds to the `WinPercentage` Property of the stat line.  But the user can just as easily pick some other Property to emphasize.

The problem (of course, you already know this, educated Stacker) is that you get an error message stating that you can't convert from `Binding` to `string`, which is what the outer `Binding` expects for `Path`. Though I haven't proven it to myself, I am guessing this is simply because `Path` is not a `DependencyProperty`.

So, is there any way to achieve my goal here? Feel free to break my assumptions in that first paragraph. Maybe, for example, `ImportantStat` can't be a `string` but must itself be a `Binding`.

**Edit: Attempt #1 Failed**

I was hoping that exposing from the code-behind a new `DependencyProperty` `Binding ImportantStatBinding` would allow me to rewrite the XAML as:

```
<PieChart Value="{Binding ImportantStatBinding, RelativeSource=... }"/>
```

...but to no avail. The indirect `Binding` is just stuck into `Value` itself with no attempts to resolve it.

My backup solution, which might be where this is headed, will be to just create the content inside the code-behind where I have access to `ImportantStat` directly and so can get away with a single `Binding.`

Comment: What is in `Stats`? It's typed as `StatList` but that is obviously a custom type of yours. Could you post some of the code of `StatList`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Far as I know, there is no way to concatenate data bindings in this way, without additional code. To put the problem more simply, we can have data binding (of course) of the form:

A --> B --> C

but you cannot have data binding of the form:

A --> B --> *A (*A indicates the target depends on the value of A)

because the relationships must be fixed.

It seems like it might be possible to create a `Converter` whose job is to convert a string into an arbitrary value by actually dereferencing a `Binding` using some additional context and that string as the property path. That sounds messy with type issues, so I chose the only other way I could think of:

I added a new `DependencyProperty` for the `PieChart` to the code behind and made sure that I constructed it at the appropriate times, so that the XAML could consume it. It's ugly, but it works. I just feel a little dead inside :) Hope someone finds this useful some day.